# Kotlin: Function declaration must have a name

Tags: kotlin

Aim of the code: Class Pair can print out Product name and quantity, Product name stored in Class Product

```
class Pair<T, U>(var product: Product, var quantity: Int) {
    for ( (product,quantity) in productAndQuantityList) {
        println("Name: ${product.productName}")
        println("Quantity: $quantity")
    }
}
```

Above Error:(2, 9) Kotlin: Expecting member declaration
Error:(2, 57) Kotlin: Function declaration must have a name

```
class ShoppingCart{
    private val productAndQuantityList = mutableListOf<Pair<Product,Int> >()
...
}

open class Product(
    val productName: String,
    var basePrice: Double,
    open val salesPrice: Double,
    val description: String) {
...}
```

---

1. may i know how to change my code?
2. after class Pair was suggested by Compiler, but should i fill in anything?
3. Which topic should i work for, to avoid the same errors again?

Thanks!

Comment: There is already a `Pair` class in kotlin so use it, move for loop code in a function as they are executable statements not declarations. Read about methods, initializers, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run the for loop when the object is instantiated, then you should use an initializer. You can't simply put statements inside class definitions directly.

```
class Pair<T, U>(var product: Product, var quantity: Int) {
  init {
    for ( (product,quantity) in productAndQuantityList) {
        println("Name: ${product.productName}")
        println("Quantity: $quantity")
    }
  }
}
```

However, this code is wrong because `Pair` does not have access to `productAndQuantityList`, although `ShoppingCart` does. As Mathias Henze suggested, you should make a function in `ShoppingCart` and move the for loop into that, like this:

```
fun printProducts() {
  for ( (product,quantity) in productAndQuantityList) {
    println("Name: ${product.productName}")
    println("Quantity: $quantity")
  }
}
```

As for your `Pair` class, the type parameters `T` and `U` are unnecessary, as you don't use them anywhere, and the class itself is provided by the standard library (The header looks something like `data class Pair<out A, out B>(val first: A, val second: B)`.

If you're determined to use your own Pair class, be sure to make it a `data class`, so it can be [destructured](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), and change the type of `productAndQuantityList` to `mutableListOf<Pair>` (without the type parameters `Pair<Product, Int>`).

### Update

Please read the answer by Mathias Henze, which is correct. My answer, was originally completely wrong, but I have now corrected it.

Comment: Error:(3, 37) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: productAndQuantityList
compiler suggests me to create local variable, but  "productAndQuantityList" has been declared in class ShoppingCart. any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I believe the feedback comment from @Mathias above is now out of date, as this answer has been substantially modified.

Answer (score 2):

The `productAndQuantityList` is just for storing the data. The `Pair` class is a provided class by Kotlin. You don't need to add anything to it in your usecase.

The ability to print the `product` and the `quantity` should be a function of the `ShoppingCart`, so just have:

```
class ShoppingCart{
    private val productAndQuantityList = mutableListOf<Pair<Product,Int> >()
    // ...
    fun printContents() {
        for ( (product,quantity) in productAndQuantityList) {
            println("Name: ${product.productName}")
            println("Quantity: $quantity")
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, that means i don't need to create Pair class as it is a provided class by Kotlin, is it?

Comment: @user12595983 yes. Pairs and Triples are part of the Kotlin stdlib. Pairs even have a second use-case in constructing maps and also have a `to` infix function. Hence you can write `val myMap = mapOf("key1" to "value1", "key2" to "value2")` to define a Map, which is the equivalent of `val myMap = mapOf(Pair("key1", "value1"), Pair("key2","value2"))`